# Unable to clear faults on Monoblock via RS232 command: Need help decoding serial messages with Arduino

Tags: serial, communication, rs232, python, serialport

I recently purchased an XRB160PN192 Monoblock with a known fault of high voltage (HV) for a low price to use in my graduation project. After reading the user manual, I found that the HV error, along with other errors, can be cleared using an RS232 command.

I decided to python to send the clear command over serial using an RS232 to USB. However, I have been unable to successfully send the command and receive a response.

Here's the python code I'm using:

```
import serial, time

ser = serial.Serial(port="COM6", baudrate=9600, parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN, bytesize=8, stopbits=1, timeout=1)

# Define message components
msg_prefix = chr(0x02) # STX
msg_body = "FLT" # replace with your message body
msg_suffix = ";" # ;<CS><CR><LF>

# Calculate checksum
checksum = sum(ord(c) for c in msg_body + msg_suffix) % 256

# Construct full message
full_msg = chr(0x02) + msg_body + chr(0x13) + str(checksum) + chr(0x0D) + chr(0x0A) # <CR><LF>

# Send message over serial port
ser.write(full_msg.encode())

# Read message from serial port "utf-8", errors='replace'
msg = ser.readline().decode("utf-8", errors='replace').strip()
#print(msg)
# Check if message has correct format
if msg.startswith(chr(0x02)) and msg.endswith(chr(0x0A)): # STX and LF
    parts = msg[1:-2].split(";")
    if len(parts) == 2:
        msg_body, checksum_str = parts
        if checksum_str.isdigit():
            checksum = int(checksum_str)
            expected_checksum = sum(ord(c) for c in msg_body + msg_suffix) % 256
            if checksum == expected_checksum:
                # Message is valid, process message body as needed
                print("YAYYY : ", msg_body)
            else:
                print("Invalid checksum:", checksum)
        else:
            print("Invalid checksum format:", checksum_str)
    else:
        print("Invalid message format:", msg)
else:
    #print(msg)
    print("Unexpected message format:", msg)

# Close serial port
ser.close()
```

Guidelines from manufacturer:

[image: Command Structure]

[image: Command Definition]

I'm not sure what's causing the issue. Is there anything I'm missing in my code or setup? How can I successfully send the clear command and receive a response as mentioned in the user manual?

This is the result if tried to establish the connection using terminal app

[image: Using Terminal App]

Comment: it's an X-ray generator ... Monoblock is just a brand name

Comment: Which board do you use. You are using two serials, are you sure the connections are OK. Is the baudrate OK. etc.

Comment: Why not using a terminal program.

Comment: @Codebeat , I tried and updated my question with a screenshot

Comment: Could the manufacturer's documentation itself be wrong? This is contradictory because the documentation says semicolon and CR are the same Hex value, 0x13. The ASCII code for semicolon is 0x3B, CR is 0x0D and LF is 0x0A. In the presented source code, CR and LF seem to be fixed, but the semicolon is used as 0x13. Please check with the manufacturer what is really the correct specification. A document that gives incorrect information may also have incorrect specifications for the checksum calculation.

Comment: @kunif , they just replied to me with the following:


the checksum is used for rs323 communication only and is computed as foloow:
- add the <CMD>,<;>, and <ARG> bytes exculding the <STX> byte into a 16 bit (or larger) word the bytes are added as unsigned integers 
-take the 2's compliment (negate it) and add the value of 1 to the resulting value.
- turncat the result down to the eight least significant bits.
- clear the most significant but (but 7) of the resultant byte, (bitwise AND with 0x7F)
- set the next most significant bit (bit 6) of the resultant byte (bitwise OR with ox40).

Comment: Did you review the documentation and program based on the manufacturer's response and did it work correctly? Please add those answers and results to the question article instead of comments. And for the CLR commands, it's probably better to get the raw hexadecimal array data to send concretely than explain the legends and basic concepts.

Answer (score 0):

You calculate the checksum incorrectly and place it in the wrong index in the array.

The D6 bit is not set by your code, and the index of the checksum byte which you have originally set to 0x13 which is index 6.

Also the argument 0x00 is after the semi-colon, and there should be no characters for argument at all, it might be best to delete it.

The document also has errors, because CR LF sequence is 13 10 in decimal, not 0x13 0x10, so you have the 0x0D 0x0A part right.

Having said this, it might be simpler to just use a PC with terminal program or C/Python/whatever code to send these strings, than always reprogram an Arduino to do it for you.

Comment: Followed your advice , tried both using pc and python, pc and terminal , no luck, i just don't get it what i'm doing wrong

Comment: Same problems. Why there is a 0x13, and the checksum calculation is actually more incorrect now than the Arduino code you removed.

Comment: So lets remove the coding part, can sending and receiving be done using putty or teraterm ?,I just want to clear the fault and check for other faults

Comment: Sure, if you can calculate and type in the checksum character.

Comment: I can assure you that no I can't. However, I am currently trying to understand the issue and I seem to be stuck.